# django problem when i start an application

Tags: django, python-2.7

When I start an application like (pages) then I link it with the project in settings => `INSTALLED_APPS`:
`INSTALLED_APPS = [ 'pages.app.PagesConfig', 'django.contrib.admin', 'django.contrib.auth', 'django.contrib.contenttypes', 'django.contrib.sessions', 'django.contrib.messages', 'django.contrib.staticfiles', ]`
**Then i made a url for it in urls:**
`from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('pages',include('pages.urls'))
]`
```

**This Error appear after running the server :**

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pages.app'`
i searched for the solution and i founed that the problem may be in the installed apps but i made it right

Answer (score 0):

i am attaching a example image , in installed apps just give the folder name (module name) you can see in the image i did 
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

in INSTALLED_APPS are listed paths of each module.
for above error

1. either just give module name like 'pages',
2. or gives its path pages.apps[its in apps file not in app].PagesConfig[if u go to apps folder u can see PagesConfig class]

'pages.apps.PagesConfig',

don't forget the comma